# CoreBluetooth: Attempt to write to device

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a connected & paired up Bluetooth LE bracelet (Service ID: FF20), which have 2 characteristics:

- 0xFF21 : Write without Response
- 0xFF22 : Notify

Now I try to write data via CoreBluetooth Framework to 0xFF21 with the following code:

I defined 2 constants at header file:

```
#define TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID @"FF20"
#define TRANSFER_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID @"FF21"
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSArray* connectedDevices = [_centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
        for (CBPeripheral *peripheral in connectedDevices) {
            NSLog(@"Device Found. CBPeripheral = %@", peripheral);
            peripheral.delegate = self;
            if(peripheral.services.count == 0) {
                NSLog(@"No service found");
            }
            for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
                if(service.characteristics != nil) {
                    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
                        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
                            // check notifying ?
                            NSData *data = [@"Testing" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"Specific Characteristic Not found");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Characteristic is NULL");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The log appears:

```
Device Found. CBPeripheral = <CBPeripheral: 0x1740f5080, identifier = 4EFF694C-017A-536F-9301-2EB2CC316CBE, name = Bracelet-0366, state = disconnected>

No service found
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Shouldn't you search for services again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to issue a connect to the discovered peripheral and get a call to your `didConnectPeripheral` delegate method before you can issue read/write requests.

When you reach the `poweredOn` state you should issue a `scanForDevicesWithServices` call, wait for the call back to your delegate, then connect, discover the service and characteristics, then you can issue a write.

```
-(void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] options:nil];
            break;
    }
}

-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"Discovered peripheral %@ (%@)",peripheral.name,peripheral.identifier.UUIDString);

    if (self.connectedPeripheral == nil) {
        [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}

-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    self.connectedPeripheral=peripheral;
    NSLog(@"Connected to %@(%@)",peripheral.name,peripheral.identifier.UUIDString);
    peripheral.delegate=self;
    [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]];
}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        NSLog(@"Discovered service %@",service.description);
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics ) {
        NSLog(@"Discovered characteristic %@(%@)",characteristic.description,characteristic.UUID.UUIDString);
        if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
            NSData *data = [@"Testing" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that from your previous question the characteristic only supports write without response, so you can't use `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`

Comment: But in my case, the device is already connected, that's why I'm using `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:` instead of `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:`

Comment: It may be connected to another app, but it isn't connected to yours.  Even if you retrieve the peripheral from `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices` you still need to connect *your* CBCentral before you can write to it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Followed your codes (forget the device in Settings already to ensure no App is using the device), I only got the `Discovered ...` line, but unable to reach `Connected to...`. To debug, I added `didFailToConnectPeripheral` delegate function, but the delegate didn't get triggered as well. I'm so confused now.

Comment: Not sure.  The code in my answer came from here - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground Perhaps you can modify that project and see if it work

Comment: I finally spotted where is the problem. In the `didDiscoverPeripheral:` of your answer, the `connectPeripheral` cannot be called immediately. After I separated the function into another `IBAction` (just like your select table row event), the device can be connected. I can now set notify on FF22, and try to write data on FF21. When I write `@"Testing"` to device, the device has no response. I guess the device only accepts certain pattern of data, which I have to further investigate.